# O que fazer com respostas duplicadas?

Tags: debate, respostas, proposta-para-faq

Quando as respostas são duplicadas com diferença de segundos ou mesmo minutos, não há problema. Mas quando há diferença de horas e principalmente dias, algo foi postado sem necessidade. Falo das respostas atrasadas/retardatárias.

Exemplo: [Validação de RG](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/71/validacao-de-rg/2136#2136)

Claramente foi um caso de "não tenho nada a acrescentar mas também quero entrar na brincadeira". Não tem utilidade alguma.

Pode se argumentar que a pergunta não ajuda, mas nem sempre é culpa da pergunta.

O SO tem sua política (não muita definida, tem moderadores dizendo o oposto exato do que fazer e o quanto isso é aceitável) mas podemos definir aqui como proceder do nosso jeito (mesmo que seja coincidente).

Devemos proteger a pergunta quando ocorre uma vez? Duas? Isso é suficiente?

Devemos votar negativamente? Além de avisar o autor.

Devemos solicitar gentilmente que ele remova sua resposta?

Devemos sinalizar (como não sendo uma resposta) e um **moderador deve removê-la?**<sup>*</sup>

Outra ação? Ou não fazer nada?

Faz diferença ter *upvote*?

---

*Sinalizar como spam trás outras consequências e não deve ser usada para isso.

Comment: Pior que isso é ver uma pessoa que pos a resposta mais "antiga" incorporar a solução da melhor que veio depois.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

> Devemos proteger a pergunta quando ocorre uma vez? Duas? Isso é suficiente?

Acho bom definirmos um parâmetro para isso. Acho que seriam pelo menos 2 ou 3 vezes para justificar a proteção. Eu raramente protejo alguma pergunta no SO, nem vejo muitas serem protegidas; isso é um recurso para perguntas que atraem muitas *views*, veremos como será aqui.

> Devemos votar negativamente? Além de avisar o autor.

Avisar o autor, acho bom. Eu não votaria negativamente só pelo fato de a resposta ser duplicada. Se for ruim, aí sim.

> Devemos solicitar gentilmente que ele remova sua resposta?

Não vejo necessidade.

> Devemos sinalizar (como não sendo uma resposta) e um moderador deve removê-la?

Não me parece o caso de "não é uma resposta". Eu não vejo por que remover esse tipo de resposta, a não ser que elas sejam uma praga na pergunta (por exemplo, numa pergunta com muitas respostas, metade é duplicada).

> Outra ação? Ou não fazer nada?

Muitas vezes é o caso de não fazer nada mesmo.

> Faz diferença ter upvote?

Se tem um ou outro upvote, e continua atrás das respostas "veteranas", eu deixaria para lá. Se conseguiu vários upvotes, de duas, uma: ou é uma boa resposta (e merece os upvotes), ou tem algo muito estranho (e talvez mereça downvote e/ou flag).

Comment: Acho importante ver os edits também, pra ver afinal de contas quem respondeu primeiro. Tem caso, como comentei aqui na pergunta, que a pessoa até respondeu antes, mas importou um conteúdo de uma melhor que veio depois. Aí dá a impressão de que o autor da resposta boa foi quem copiou/repetiu. Nesse caso com certeza eu dou downvote (ao menos até que alguém proponha saída melhor).

Comment: @Bacco Pessoalmente, não concordo com isso. Se eu sinto que minha resposta precisa ser aprimorada, eu aprimoro, ainda que a informação venha de uma resposta "concorrente". Mas claro, sempre **cito a fonte*** (além de votar positivo na resposta em questão).

Comment: @mgibsonbr Você pega o conteúdo da resposta que foi dada pra mesma pergunta por outra pessoa e "importa" na sua??

Comment: @Bacco De certa forma, sim (embora na maioria das vezes é uma adaptação, não cópia direta). [Exemplo](http://br.stackoverflow.com/questions/636/como-detectar-o-encoding-da-pagina-por-php/640#640), [exemplo](http://br.stackoverflow.com/questions/1823/como-ler-um-arquivo-de-texto-em-java/1825#1825), [mais-ou-menos-exemplo](http://br.stackoverflow.com/questions/889/como-comparar-elementos-html-por-z-index-real/931#931), [exemplo](http://br.stackoverflow.com/questions/1496/problema-ao-acessar-um-arquivo-acentuado-caractere-combinante/1515#1515). Se vir problemas em qq uma delas, favor comentar.

Answer (score 8):

Recentemente tivemos uma pergunta parecida, mas me parece que teve uma visibilidade maior. A pergunta [not all code paths return a value](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/202124/20615) recebeu 8 respostas com 3 respostas iguais.

É válido dizer que 5 das 8 respostas vieram em um intervalo de 5 minutos, o que eu acho válido para alguém que estava respondendo concluir a resposta sem *copiar* da outra. Minha dúvida é em relação as demais, que são parecidas e vieram mais de 15 minutos após a última resposta, tendo um sendo horas após a última resposta.

Neste caso, essas respostas receberam 13 upvotes em conjunto (6, 6 e 1) e quase 40% das respostas são duplicadas.

Mesmo neste caso, não devemos fazer nada?

Comment: Realmente analisando as 3 últimas respostas, é visível que são cópias das melhores respostas, na minha opinião, deveria fazer algo sim, até mesmo a remoção dessas respostas e/ou uma penalização/advertência por resposta igual a outra já informada. [solução] talvez comparando os caracteres de alguma resposta já mencionada, verificando se existem muitos outros caracteres diferentes, fazendo assim, acredito que "entenderia" que é "outra resposta", pois se já existe uma resposta, pra que colocar outra resposta igual? Concordam ?

Comment: Há pessoal que abre o campo de resposta e vai escrevendo, entretanto vão fazendo outras coisas e depois é que envia, 15 minutos não me parece uma boa medida. Se fosse um dia depois, isso sim seria resposta duplicata. E mesmo assim parece-me que o ideal é manter. Pode sempre acrescentar mais alguma coisa, quem decide se acrescenta ou não?