# FAQ da comunidade

Tags: suporte, faq, destaque

> *Para um guia oficial acesse a **[Central de Ajuda](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help)***.

### Perguntando

- **[Guia de sobrevivência do Stack Overflow em Português](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8045/101)** (**não deixe de ler**)
- [Que erro cometi ao formular minha pergunta?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/8388/que-erro-cometi-ao-formular-minha-pergunta)
- [Posso mostrar só um link pro meu site com problemas?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1913/posso-mostrar-s%c3%b3-um-link-pro-meu-site-com-problemas)
- [Quando se deve colocar o nome da linguagem no título?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/297/quando-se-deve-colocar-o-nome-da-linguagem-no-t%c3%adtulo)
- [Posso fazer crosspost entre o SO em Inglês e o SO em Português?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/125/posso-fazer-crosspost-entre-o-so-em-ingl%c3%aas-e-o-so-em-portugu%c3%aas)
- [Tradução de perguntas e FAQs](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/11/tradu%c3%a7%c3%a3o-de-perguntas-e-faqs)
- [Como criar um exemplo Mínimo, Completo e Verificável](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1186/como-criar-um-exemplo-m%C3%ADnimo-completo-e-verific%C3%A1vel)
- [Manual de como NÃO fazer perguntas](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5483/manual-de-como-n%c3%83o-fazer-perguntas)
- [Checklist de perguntas do Stack Overflow](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/8496/checklist-de-perguntas-do-stack-overflow)

### Respondendo

- [Queremos respostas que contenham somente links?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/42/queremos-respostas-que-contenham-somente-links)
- [O problema dos Vampiros de Ajuda](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1160/o-problema-dos-vampiros-de-ajuda)
- [Respondi uma questão e tempos depois encontrei uma solução melhor. Como fazer?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/322/respondi-uma-quest%c3%a3o-e-tempos-depois-encontrei-uma-solu%c3%a7%c3%a3o-melhor-como-fazer)
- [Respondi minha própria pergunta, fiz algo errado?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/37/respondi-minha-pr%c3%b3pria-pergunta-fiz-algo-errado)

### Aceitando respostas

- [Como e por que aceitar uma resposta?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1078/como-e-por-que-aceitar-uma-resposta/)
- [Devemos ter pressa ao aceitar respostas?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/494/devemos-ter-pressa-ao-aceitar-respostas)
- [Como dizer obrigado em respostas?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/605/como-dizer-obrigado-em-respostas)

### Editando perguntas e respostas

- [Como devemos formatar perguntas e respostas?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1084/como-devemos-formatar-perguntas-e-respostas?lq=1)
- [JS, CSS e HTML executáveis no corpo da pergunta ou resposta](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2115/apresentando-js-css-e-html-execut%C3%A1veis)
- [Deveremos manter algum padrão linguístico ou não?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/3/deveremos-de-manter-algum-standard-linguistico-ou-n%c3%a3o)

### Votos

- [Por que não é obrigatório comentar ao dar voto negativo, e por que sugestões para que seja obrigatório não são bem recebidas?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/8788/por-que-n%c3%a3o-%c3%a9-obrigat%c3%b3rio-comentar-ao-dar-voto-negativo-e-por-que-sugest%c3%b5es-par)

### Sobre postagens em geral

- [Como funciona a marcação de "Wiki da Comunidade"](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/762/como-funciona-a-marca%c3%a7%c3%a3o-de-wiki-da-comunidade)
- [Como se portar ao perguntar/responder?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/38/como-se-portar-ao-perguntar-responder)
- [Perguntas/respostas traduzidas devem conter link para o conteúdo original?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/25/perguntas-respostas-traduzidas-devem-conter-link-para-o-conte%c3%bado-original)

### Contas de usuário, perfis e acesso

- [Tenho duas ou mais contas de usuário, como fundi-las em uma só?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1110/)

### Comentários e notificações

- [Como funcionam as menções e notificações com @usuario?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/943/como-funcionam-as-men%C3%A7%C3%B5es-e-notifica%C3%A7%C3%B5es-com-usuario)
- [Quais são todos os magic links que possuímos?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1616/quais-s%c3%a3o-todos-os-magic-links-que-possu%c3%admos)

### Etiquetando

- [Como dizer obrigado em respostas?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/605/como-dizer-obrigado-em-respostas)
- [Existem tags implícitas?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/468/existem-tags-impl%c3%adcitas)
- [Precisamos de padronização para tags com mais de uma palavra?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/443/precisamos-de-padroniza%c3%a7%c3%a3o-para-tags-com-mais-de-uma-palavra)
- [Como tratar tags em árvore?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/310/como-tratar-tags-em-%c3%a1rvore)
- [Diretrizes para criação de tag wikis](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/300/diretrizes-para-cria%c3%a7%c3%a3o-de-tag-wikis)
- [O que fazer se a tag para a minha pergunta não existe?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1434/o-que-fazer-se-a-tag-para-a-minha-pergunta-n%c3%a3o-existe)

### Moderação

- [Como eu posso ajudar a comunidade? Preciso ser moderador para isso?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/8437/como-eu-posso-ajudar-a-comunidade-preciso-ser-moderador-para-isso)
- [O que é a eleição? Como ela funciona?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3882/12)
- [Lidando com perguntas duplicadas](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/607/lidando-com-perguntas-duplicadas)
- [O que fazer com respostas duplicadas?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/508/o-que-fazer-com-respostas-duplicadas)
- [O que é o "problema XY"?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/499/o-que-%c3%a9-o-problema-xy)
- [O que fazer com respostas que são boas mas não respondem o que foi perguntado?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/491/o-que-fazer-com-respostas-que-s%c3%a3o-boas-mas-n%c3%a3o-respondem-o-que-foi-perguntado)
- [O nível de detalhamento de uma pergunta de utilidade publica e não conceitual é motivo para fecha-la?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/885/o-n%C3%ADvel-de-detalhamento-de-uma-pergunta-de-utilidade-publica-e-n%C3%A3o-conceitual-%C3%A9)
- [Como lidar com perguntas com certo grau de subjetividade?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/482/como-lidar-com-perguntas-com-certo-grau-de-subjetividade)
- [Revisão de perguntas ou respostas em pt_PT para pt_BR ou vice-versa, como agir?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/292/revis%c3%a3o-de-perguntas-ou-respostas-em-pt-pt-para-pt-br-ou-vice-versa-como-agir)
- [Stack Overflow em português é somente o StackOverflow em português ou é mais abrangente?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/112/stack-overflow-em-portugu%C3%AAs-%C3%A9-somente-o-stackoverflow-em-portugu%C3%AAs-ou-%C3%A9-mais-abr)
- [O problema dos Vampiros de Ajuda](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1160/o-problema-dos-vampiros-de-ajuda)

---

### A sua pergunta não está aqui na FAQ?

Primeiro procure na tag [proposta-para-faq](/questions/tagged/proposta-para-faq) para ver se não há algo parecido está sendo considerada para FAQ. Se ainda não achar, siga as instruções para incluir uma pergunta na FAQ:

- Pergunte só o fundamental do que você deseja de forma clara e simples. E responda separadamente como uma resposta.
- Coloque um link para esta página no final da pergunta. Cole o código:

  ```
   [Retornar para o índice da FAQ](/q/699)
  ```
- Coloque as tags [suporte](/questions/tagged/suporte) e [proposta-para-faq](/questions/tagged/proposta-para-faq). Quando o post estiver maduro o suficiente, um moderador colocará a tag [faq](/questions/tagged/faq).
- Sinalize para um moderador marcar a pergunta como *Community Wiki*. Todos posts da FAQ precisam ser CW.
- **Após** a pergunta receber a tag [faq](/questions/tagged/faq), edite este post para colocar um link para a pergunta na seção adequada.

Não tente fazer de outra forma, precisamos manter a organização.

Comment: O ideal é que esta pergunta seja a mais votada do site. Já pedi para transformar em CW. Ajudem a criar esta FAQ. Está baseada na original que pode ser usada como guia para evoluir a nossa e, por enquanto, de orientação para quem sabe inglês: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7931/faq-for-stack-exchange-sites

Comment: A atualização que acabo de fazer nessa lista é preliminar. Gostaria de ver mais gente editando e incluindo conteúdo antes de "carimbar" as perguntas com a tag [meta-tag:faq].

Comment: Precisava tomar o carimbo [meta-tag:featured] por algumas semanas pra ser a mais votada do site... Registrando umas possíveis candidatas [{1: saudações e agradecimentos}](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/846), [{2: edição de código}](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/749) e [{3: ortografia}](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/767). Acho que [esta aqui sobre Syntax Highlight](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/33) precisava de um outro título pra virar FAQ. cc bigown / @bfavaretto

Comment: Boa ideia @brasofilo, coloquei em destaque. Não vou inserir as candidatas por enquanto, vamos ver o que a comunidade faz por conta própria.

Comment: Registro de 128 visitas hoje.

Comment: Quase 1 mês após o destaque, 258 visitas. Vou deixar em destaque mais um pouco. @brasofilo

Comment: Eu acho que tem que ficar a maior parte do tempo em destaque, e só sair espordicamente quando outros assuntos realmente importantes estiverem "bombando".