# Como funciona a marcação de "Wiki da Comunidade"

Tags: suporte, faq, wiki-comunitário

Algumas perguntas e respostas são marcadas como *Wiki da Comunidade*.

- Como funciona um post *Wiki da Comunidade*?
- Como fazer a marcação de *Wiki da Comunidade* de uma pergunta e resposta?
- Como remover a marcação de *Wiki da Comunidade* de uma pergunta e de uma resposta?

[Retorne para o índice da FAQ](/q/699)

Comment: Vou começar a traduzir esse faq

Mas primeiro "Wiki da Comunidade" eu acho que ficaria muito mais claro se fosse "Resposta comunitária (Wiki)" e "Pergunta comunitária (wiki)". Bem o termo "Wiki da Comunidade" não me leva a entender que é para a comunidade participar.

Comment: É, esse termo não é bom mesmo, mas não gosto de desmembrá-lo em dois. Note que aqui no meta a tag se semana "wiki-comunitário", talvez seja um pouco melhor. (Usei essa tag pois já está devidamente linkada com o equivalente em inglês.)

Comment: "wiki-comunitário" ficaria bem mais claro, passa uma informação de que se é comunitário eu posso colaborar, mas como ficaria isso em pt-pt, fica claro também?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

<sub>Fonte: [What are “Community Wiki” posts?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/11740)</sub>

Um dos objetivos do site é evoluir constantemente como uma boa fonte de informação. Os posts  (perguntas e/ou respostas) Wiki da Comunidade ajudam a aumentar o aspecto "wiki" do site.

### Como funciona um post Wiki da Comunidade?

Um post wiki da comunidade transfere a propriedade de um post do autor original para a comunidade. Isso faz com que o post seja mais fácil de editar e manter por um grupo amplo de usuários, mas não há ganho de reputação para nenhum dos usuários.

Alguns dos aspectos-chave são:

- Posts Wiki da Comunidade são propriedade do Usuário Comunidade <sup>1</sup>, e não de um usuário individual.
- A reputação requerida para editar um post wiki é muito mais baixa, **100** invés de **2000** <sup>2</sup>.
- Os votos positivos ou negativos em um post wiki não afetam a reputação de nenhum usuário.
- Aceitar uma resposta marcada como wiki da comunidade [não afeta a reputação do autor](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/145935).
- Recompensas a uma resposta marcada como wiki concedem reputação como de costume.
- O autor original do post receberá medalhas derivadas de um wiki da comunidade.
- O autor original manterá a reputação ganha (ou perdida) antes que o post fosse marcado como wiki.
- O autor original receberá notificações sobre edições ou comentários feitos no post.

### Como fazer a marcação de Wiki da Comunidade de uma pergunta e resposta?

Há três maneiras de converter um post em wiki da comunidade.

- O autor da **resposta** marca o *checkbox* *wiki da comunidade* ao escrever ou editar uma resposta. Observando que esse *checkbox* não está disponível para novos usuários e que não aparece se a pergunta já é um wiki da comunidade. <sup>3</sup>
- Um moderador tem razões para acreditar que o post servirá melhor como wiki da comunidade - ou se você [acha que deve ser convertido](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/08/the-future-of-community-wiki/), sinalize o post para [atenção dos moderadores](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/392/should-the-community-wiki-police-be-shut-down/7183#7183).
- Uma resposta publicada em uma pergunta wiki da comunidade também será marcada como wiki. Antigamente, as perguntas podiam ser marcadas como wiki pelos seus autores ou automaticamente em certos casos, mas atualmente a única maneira de converter a pergunta em wiki é por ação de um moderador. Quando um moderador converte uma pergunta em wiki, todas as respostas também serão convertidas assim como qualquer resposta futura.

<sup>** as regras acima são baseadas no post [What are “Community Wiki” posts?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/11740) e que podem ser (ou ter sido) alteradas sem notificação prévia*</sup>

### Como remover a marcação de Wiki da Comunidade de uma pergunta e de uma resposta?

[Moderadores podem remover a marcação quando necessário](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2974/is-there-a-way-to-remove-community-wiki-status/83373#83373).

### Miscelâneas

- Reverter a versão de um post não remove o status de wiki da comunidade.
- O Usuário Comunidade <sup>1</sup> pode aparecer como último editor de uma pergunta, mesmo de uma pergunta não-wiki. Isso acontece quando o sistema coloca perguntas antigas sem resposta para ganhar atenção na página inicial do site

---

<sup>1</sup> Vide [Who is the Community User?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19738/who-is-the-community-user), ou leia o [perfil do Usuário Comunidade](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/-1).

<sup>2</sup> O autor original de um post wiki sempre pode editá-lo, mesmo que tenha menos de 100 pontos de reputação.

<sup>3</sup> Desde [Outubro de 2010](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/67582) já não existe o *checkbox* "wiki da comunidade" ao fazer uma pergunta.

Answer (score 7):

As vezes algum usuário não pode ou não quer reter sozinho a "autoria" de um post. Existem vários motivos para isso, mas dois são mais comuns:

- O desejo de que todos entendam que o post pode ser alterado de forma considerável por qualquer pessoa, a qualquer momento (tornando o post, bem, um *wiki* mesmo :D ) - infelizmente é comum pessoas se sentirem incomodadas quando seus posts são editados.
- Quando um usuário é removido, seus posts podem se tornar wikis da comunidade.

Você pode criar uma resposta  wiki marcando a caixinha de seleção no canto inferior e a direita da caixa de texto do post.

Com o privilégio que mencionas, você pode editar esses posts. Lembre-se de que com grandes poderes vêm grandes responsabilidades, ok?

Comment: A conta Comunidade não consta como autora desses posts. A diferença é que autoria e editores são mostrados de maneira mais discreta. Aparece o nome de quem mais contribuiu, sem avatar; mesmo assim o histórico de revisões mostra todos os autores e editores.

Comment: @bfavaretto mudei a palavra para "dono" :) Tomei como base o post que o brasofilo menciona na outra resposta wiki aqui.

Comment: Acho que mais do que "Você pode criar um post wiki" seria "Você pode criar uma resposta wiki". . . . . Pelo que entendi depois de fazer a tradução, me parece equivocado dizer que o usuário Comunidade tem a *ownership* de posts wiki.

Comment: Fiz mais alterações. Mas pessoal, isso é uma resposta wiki, sintam-se a vontade para meter a mão na massa e alterá-la a vontade!