# Como funcionam as menções e notificações com @usuario?

Tags: suporte, faq, notificações

Quando vou mencionar alguém digitando @fulano, não aparece nenhum destaque ou algo que possa simbolizar que isto é uma menção a alguém. Isso acontece nas respostas e comentários, apenas fica como texto comum.

Li o help que diz:

> Geralmente é suficiente mencionar apenas o primeiro nome do usuário
>   cujo comentário você estiver respondendo, por ex. @ben ou @marc. No
>   entanto, talvez deva ser mais específico se três pessoas chamadas Ben
>   tiverem respondido em comentários anteriores, adicionando o primeiro
>   caractere do sobrenome, por ex. @benm ou @benc Os espaços não são
>   válidos nos nomes em respostas a comentários, portanto não use @peter
>   smith, sempre use @peters ou @petersmith.

E também outro help que diz:

> Os comentários usam formatação do mini-Markdown: 
>   [link](http://example.com) *itálico* **negrito** `código`. O autor da
>   publicação sempre será notificado sobre seu comentário. Para também
>   notificar pessoas que tenham feito comentários anteriormente, mencione
>   o nome de usuário deles: @peter ou @PeterSmith funcionarão.

Mas como saber se o outro usuário está sendo notificado?
Não deveria ser algo semelhante às *hashtags* do Facebook?

[Retorne para o índice da FAQ](/q/699)

Answer (score 14):

### Onde usar notificações com @usuario?

Essas notificações funcionam somente em comentários e no chat, não funcionam no corpo de perguntas ou respostas. Além disso, o sistema trata essas menções como parte normal do comentário, sem nenhuma formatação especial.

### Quem posso notificar com @usuario em comentários?

Comentários com @usuario só geram notificações para usuários que:

1. tiverem comentado no mesmo post em que você está comentando; ou
2. tiverem editado o post onde você está comentando (mesmo que não seja o último editor); ou
3. sejam moderadores ♦ (com o diamante ao lado do nome de usuário) e tiverem fechado a pergunta; ou
4. tenham uma recompensa ativa na pergunta

Não é possível notificar mais de um usuário a partir de um mesmo comentário.

<sup>Um post é uma pergunta *ou* resposta específica. Se alguém comentou somente na pergunta, não é possível notificá-lo a partir de uma resposta; se alguém comentou em uma resposta, não é possível notificá-lo a partir da pergunta ou de outra resposta.</sup>

### Que acontece quando edito o comentário?

Quando editar um comentário dentro do limite de tempo (5 minutos), se trocar ou adicionar um @usuario, a notificação [pode ou não chegar](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/40989/will-edited-comments-reach-addressees/74781#74781) ao destinatário.

### Quando ocorre notificação automática, sem @usuario?

1. Se você é o autor de um post, será notificado de todos os comentários embaixo do seu post.
2. Se você foi o único a comentar em um post e o autor do post comentar de volta, você será notificado dessas respostas.

### Por que às vezes o autocompletar não aparece?

O sistema não oferece autocompletar em casos de notificação automática implícita, ou quando o outro usuário for um editor, moderador ♦ que fechou a pergunta, ou tenha uma recompensa ativa na pergunta.

### Como selecionar um nome no autocompletar?

Ao começar a digitar `@`, aparece uma lista suspensa com o nome do usuário(s). Use a tecla <kbd>Tab</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> para executar o autocompletar. Se mais de um usuário aparece na lista suspensa, vá clicando <kbd>Tab</kbd> até destacar o nome desejado e clique <kbd>Enter</kbd> para selecionar.

### Qual é o formato das @menções?

- Pelo menos 3 letras (a menos que o primeiro nome do usuário só tenha duas)
- *Case-insensitive*
- Espaços no nome do usuário são removidos
- Pontos, hífens, aspas e underscores devem ser mantidos
- Alguns caracteres acentuados são reconhecidos sem acento

---

#### Referências

- [How do comment @replies work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43019/how-do-comment-replies-work)

Comment: Lembro que, no Stack Overflow em inglês, havia algo particular em relação àqueles usuários ‘user999’, que não recebem (recebiam?) notificações. Não sei se estou lembrando corretamente e se essa distinção ainda existe.

Answer (score 0):

Há a exibição da lista suspensa de acordo com os comentários anteriores **na mesma pergunta**, mas não é possível navegar por eles via teclado (estou usando o Google Chrome). Eles também não parecem incluir hiperlinks ou algo do tipo.

[image: Autocomplete]

Comment: Estou usando Google Chrome, e nem sequer esta caixa aparece, olha que usei CTRL+F5 pra limpar o cache, e ver havia uma atualização de código frontend (html, css e javascript).

Comment: Também uso Google Chrome e não aparecem as opções. Nem precisava fazer link, mas ajudar a escrever o nome da pessoa ajuda :p

Comment: @MayogaX para mim apareceu quando digitei "@M" agora

Comment: @MayogaX principalmente quando o nome de usuário é user12345678900987654321

Comment: Adicionei um esclarecimento na resposta do bfavaretto explicando como funciona.