# Tradução da central de ajuda na parte de privilégios de comentários

Tags: bug, status-pronto, internacionalização

Estava a olhar os privilégios e me deparei com alguns blocos não traduzidos:

[image: falta de tradução]

https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment

Comment: O link no final da nota também poderia levar para o mais próximo que temos em português: http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/943/como-funcionam-as-men%C3%A7%C3%B5es-e-notifica%C3%A7%C3%B5es-com-usuario

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O item da lista foi alterado para:

> - **outro** usuário quando seu comentário mencioná-lo com uma com @resposta<sup>1</sup>

E o outro parágrafo teve seu início alterado para:

> <sup>1</sup> Você só pode deixar @respostas para usuários que (...)

Com o link apontando para [a resposta no nosso meta](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/943/como-funcionam-as-men%C3%A7%C3%B5es-e-notifica%C3%A7%C3%B5es-com-usuario), conforme sugestão do @bfavaretto