# Tenho duas ou mais contas de usuário, como fundi-las em uma só?

Tags: suporte, faq, contas-usuário

Acabei criando outro usuário com o mesmo nome, acontece que eu sempre entrei no site normalmente, mas dessa vez me obrigou a criar um usuário novo, não sei porque.

Como eu faço para transferir meus pontos e medalhas para esse novo usuário?

[Retorne para o índice da FAQ](/q/699)

Answer (score 9):

Provavelmente você tentou fazer login com um provedor de autenticação diferente (ex.: Google, Facebook, Yahoo, OpenID) e - sem reconhecer as duas contas como a mesma - o sistema acabou por criar um novo usuário. Se você ainda tem acesso à sua outra conta (você lembra o meio que você usou para se logar anteriormente? ainda tem acesso a ele?) os moderadores podem mesclá-las para você. Caso contrário, não sei, pois seria necessário provar que você é mesmo o dono da outra conta.

Nota: no seu perfil, existe um link "meus log-ins" onde você pode associar duas ou mais formas de autenticação diferentes, de modo que o sistema reconheça qualquer um deles como o login da sua conta. Ao recuperar acesso à sua conta principal, faça isso, associe todas as suas contas externas [que você quiser associar, é claro] com sua conta no SE, assim qualquer uma delas poderá ser usada para login, no mesmo perfil de usuário.

Mais informações na Central de Ajuda: ["I accidentally created two accounts; how do I merge them?"](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/merging-accounts)

Sumarizando aqui o procedimento:

1. [Recupere o acesso](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/account-recovery) à sua conta antiga (caso não o tenha). Você terá que se lembrar do e-mail que usou para criá-la.
2. Edite o seu perfil principal, e na seção "Sobre mim" acrescente "mesclar manter".
3. Edite o seu outro perfil, e na seção "Sobre mim" acrescente "mesclar excluir".
4. Use a [página de contato](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/contact) para requisitar a mesclagem das duas contas.

   1. Use a opção "I need to merge user profiles".
   2. Coloque os links dos dois perfis que precisam ser mesclados.