# Fiz uma pergunta mas não consegui entrar mais na conta

Tags: debate

Fiz uma pergunta e ela foi respondida o ultimo comentario funcionou, mas nao consigo comentar nem fazer nada.

[Preciso buscar dados em uma tabela referente a um atrelamento da mesma tabela](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/491906/preciso-buscar-dados-em-uma-tabela-referente-a-um-atrelamento-da-mesma-tabela)

Comment: Este é um problema que deve ser resolvido via [formulário de contato](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/contact) no rodapé do site. O usuário fez a pergunta com uma conta não registrada, depois tentou acessar com uma conta registrada. A solução é a [mesclagem das contas](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1110/70), e isto é feito pelos funcionários da SE - Dada a atual situação, já adiantei o assunto para o Staff.

Comment: **Atualização:** a SE fez a mesclagem das contas, agora esta conta aqui ficou sendo a mesma da postagem linkada.