# Como criar um exemplo Mínimo, Completo e Verificável

Tags: suporte, faq, perguntas, central-de-ajuda

> **Esta tradução acabou sendo adotada oficialmente na Central e ajuda, com pequenas alterações. Acesse: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve**

### Como criar um exemplo Mínimo, Completo e Verificável

Ao perguntar sobre um problema no seu código, você conseguirá melhores respostas se der às pessoas código que elas possam usar para reproduzir o problema. Esse código deve ser…

- …Mínimo – Use o mínimo possível de código capaz de reproduzir o problema
- …Completo – Forneça todas as partes necessárias para se reproduzir o problema
- …Verificável - Teste o código antes de postar para confirmar que ele reproduz o problema

### Mínimo

Quanto maior o código, menor a chance de alguém enxergar o problema. Simplifique seu exemplo usando uma destas técnicas:

1. **Recomece do zero.** Crie um novo programa, e só inclua nele o necessário para reproduzir o problema. Isso pode ser mais rápido para grandes sistemas, quando você acredita saber a origem do problema. Também é útil se não puder postar o código em público por razões legais ou éticas.
2. **Dividir e conquistar.** Se o código for pequeno, mas você não tem ideia da causa do problema, comece a remover um pedaço de código por vez até que o problema suma – e então inclua essa última parte de volta.

#### Mínimo *e* legível

Mínimo não quer dizer necessariamente o mais *curto* possível – um exemplo *claro* é melhor que um exemplo *pequeno*. Use nomes e indentação consistentes, e se necessário inclua comentários para explicar partes do código. Praticamente todos os editores de código têm um um comando de autoformatação – encontre e use! E **não use tabs** – elas podem aparecer bem no seu editor, mas no Stack Overflow podem sair bagunçadas.

### Completo

Certifique-se de incluir toda a informação necessária para reproduzir o problema:

- Algumas pessoas vão querer testar a resposta antes de postar.
- O problema às vezes não está onde você pensa, mas em outra parte do código.

  Se o problema requer código *server-side* ou um arquivo de configuração XML, inclua ambos. Se um problema num site requer HTML, JavaScript e CSS, inclua os três.

### Verificável

Para ajudá-lo a resolver seu problema, as pessoas primeiro precisam comprovar que ele existe:

- **Elimine qualquer aspecto que não seja relevante para a pergunta.** Se a pergunta não for sobre um erro de compilação, garanta que não haja nenhum erro desse tipo. Use ferramentas como o [JSLint](http://www.jslint.com/) para validar linguagens interpretadas. Sempre valide o HTML ou XML.
- **Garanta que o exemplo realmente reproduza o problema!** Se você resolveu o problema por acaso enquanto criava o exemplo mas não testou de novo, pode não perceber que o código que está postando não ajuda.

Em certos casos ajuda desligar e reiniciar o sistema, ou testar o exemplo em outra máquina para confirmar que de fato esteja entregando um exemplo válido do problema.

Para mais informações sobre como depurar seu programa para criar um exemplo mínimo, o [Eric Lippert](https://stackoverflow.com/users/88656/eric-lippert) criou um blog post incrível sobre o assunto: *[How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)* <sup>(en)</sup>. Veja em português: [Como debugar programas pequenos](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7785/101).

[Retorne para o índice da FAQ](/q/699)

Comment: Esse tipo de coisa é que precisamos aqui! Acho que se perde muito tempo tentando inventar moda, e em compensação conseguir arrumar tradução e conserto de bug parece uma novela.

Comment: @Gabe Desde que escrevi isso me incomoda o termo "conciso" na primeira frase da seção *Mínimo e legível*. Vamos trocar para "sucinto" ou "curto"? Concisão me parece positivo, os outros são mais neutros e dependem do contexto (puxam mais para o comprimento). Estou editando aqui já. Lembrando: no original é *terse*.

Comment: Esse tipo de conteúdo com certeza ajuda os que estão entrando.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Nossa primeira **nova** página de ajuda!

#### https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Não tive certeza entre manter o padrão com o Help Center ou aportuguesar a URL para /emcv. Estou aberto à sugestões. Parabéns ao @bfavaretto pelo excelente trabalho de tradução e principalmente por ter visto o problema e caçado a "solução".

Quanto ao conteúdo em sí, lê-lo é muito importante e indicá-lo para os usuários que apresentarem problemas na criação das perguntas também. O Stack Overflow é um trabalho conjunto, e é importante que você ajude os outros a te ajudar. Um bom exemplo leva à uma boa pergunta, que não precisa ser esclarecida por comentários por horas à fio até que alguém entenda o que se passa.

### Trabalheira desnecessária...

Pode parecer um *overhead* muito grande, ter que criar um novo programa, ver se o erro acontece, buscar todas as partes do código que podem ser relevantes (configurações, versões, etc), se certificar de que o erro acontece em outras circunstâncias, tudo isso pode parecer pedante mas é importante lembrar de duas coisas:

1. As pessoas que vão te ajudar precisam bater o olho no seu post e imediatamente entender o que se passa. Não necessariamente **ver o erro**, mas entender o contexto. E é aí que entra um bom exemplo. O SO é baseado na comunicação assíncrona... Eu posso responder sua pergunta às 3 da manhã do dia seguinte, e você não vai estar lá para me esclarecer as coisas, então é necessário que seu exemplo me permita te ajudar.
2. Como tudo em programação, quanto mais você faz mais rápido você fica. No começo vai dar mais trabalho conseguir montar o seu exemplo, mas com o tempo tudo se torna mais tranquilo por **já saber** o que é necessário para montar um bom post.

A facilidade adquirida para montar um bom exemplo com o tempo se deve ao que, talvez, seja minha característica preferida do SO...

### Patinhos de Borracha

A ideia de [Rubber Duck Debugging](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging)<sup>(en)</sup> é que ao explicar seu problema para um patinho de borracha às vezes você "magicamente", descobre o que estava errado. Explicar seu problema para alguém é uma forma de olhar para ele sob um novo ponto de vista, e te permite ver coisas que você não notava enquanto dava porradas na mesa.

O Stack Overflow funciona muito bem como pato de borracha (**atenção:** Não jogue seu computador na piscina), e ao montar o seu EMCV por diversas vezes você vai enxergar a solução, sem sequer criar a pergunta. A criação de um EMCV é uma excelente forma de realmente compreender de onde vem o seu problema, de ver claramente os fatores que fazem parte dele e de montar uma bom mapa mental do que está acontecendo.

O esforço de criação de um EMCV pode parecer desnecessário para quem vem de outras ferramentas (fóruns ou listas de discussão), mas tenho certeza de que bastam poucas perguntas para que os benefícios se tornem claros.