# Pergunta mal formulada?

Tags: debate, suporte, pergunta-específica

Tenho uma pergunta que faz alguns dias que não tem resposta nem feedback de ninguém.

Não sei se é porque [minha pergunta está mal formulada](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/64831/fazer-mestre-detalhe-usando-listview) ou se é porque não existe resposta pra minha pergunta.

Gostaria de saber o que fazer pra que eu possa melhorar a pergunta pra que não seja uma dúvida só minha, mas que possa ser outras pessoas e assim enriquecer o conteúdo do SOpt

Comment: +1 por querer enriquecer o conteúdo SOPT e por já ter lido o tour até o final :)

Comment: @Math valeu pela força. Quero que o SOpt seja uma referência, pra isso quero dar minha contribuição de forma que isso seja possível!

Comment: Eu não entendi isto na sua pergunta: *Mas como muito novo em WinForms não tenho muita ideia de como fazer isso.*, você quer dizer que você é muito novo nesta área ou você quer dizer que algo mudou no uso do winforms?

Comment: Quer dizer que to engatinhando ainda em winforms.. =[

Comment: Não entendi o que é que você está perguntando exatamente. Não entendi qual é a sua dúvida ou o que você está tentando fazer. Mas como nunca mexi com WinForms, eu nem poderia te ajudar mesmo. :(

Comment: @VictorStafusa eu queria fazer tipo duas tabelas. Uma para mostrar informações de um aluno e na outra mostrar as ocorrências dele, que são relacionadas sabe ? Acho que acgora ficou mais claro né ? KK

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Não considero a pergunta citada ruim. Porém, alguns dos motivos que podem levá-lo a não obter resposta são:

1. **Contexto muito grande**: não sei se é realmente o caso, mas dá a entender que é preciso ler o tutorial linkado para então ler a pergunta e depois começar a responder.
2. **Tamanho da pergunta**: não que seja demasiadamente grande, mas muitos usuários desistem de ler porque o tamanho passa a impressão de que é necessário gastar algum tempo para respondê-la. Por exemplo, assim que eu vejo uma pergunta no *feed*, a primeira coisa que eu faço é pensar se posso responder. A segundo é dar uma olhada geral e calcular se tenho tempo hábil de respondê-la no momento. Se achar que não dá tempo, posso fechar e deixar para outra pessoa responder ou salvá-la para mais tarde, o que nem sempre funciona, já que o dia-a-dia acaba sendo corrido.
3. **Dificuldade de reproduzir**: embora você tenha dado vários exemplos, para que haja uma resposta realmente boa, o autor dela terá que criar um protótipo por si mesmo. Eu não sei se a pergunta dá todos os elementos para isso, mas quem for responder precisará fazê-lo. Na verdade, é até possível responder "de cabeça", mas aí a solução não será tão confiável e o autor pode acabar escorregando em algum ponto.

Enfim, perguntas que só são bem respondidas quando há necessidade de refazer o exemplo e/ou entender um contexto grande, são muito mais propensas a caírem no limbo, esperando talvez a boa vontade de um herói disposto a encarar o desafio. A maioria dos usuários prefere perguntas simples e diretas, mas claro, há exceções.

O que fazer quanto a esses pontos:

1. Isole mais o seu problema. Talvez seja possível dividir sua questão em duas ou até mais. Não há uma solução fácil, mas ajudaria a não ter tantos pontos de interrogação numa mesma questão.
2. Dose o nível de detalhes. É complicado, eu sei. Às vezes você resume e os usuários pedem mais, às vezes você coloca mais eles dizem que está muito ampla. Mas, neste caso, será que não dava pra resumir sem perder muita informação?
3. Crie um [projeto de exemplo mínimo, completo e verificável](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1186/227). Assim os usuários podem continuar de onde você parou, não recomeçar do zero.

Lembro que sua pergunta não está ruim, e nem sempre é possível aplicar todos os pontos acima, principalmente em casos que são maiores e complexos por natureza. Mas essas são coisas que você sempre deve ter em mente.

Comment: Mas utluiz, eu fiz uma edição pra colocar alguns códigos que tenho. Pra pergunta não ficar muito vaga e dar a impressão que quero que a comunidade faça pra mim. Fiz mal em coloca os códigos ?

Comment: @Érik Fez muito bem em colocar o código. O que eu quis dizer, resumidamente, é que às vezes a pergunta fica sem resposta porque dá trabalho responder e naquele momento não há ninguém com tempo ou disposição necessárias. Uma dica: você pode tentar pedir ajuda no chat para ver se desperta o interesse de alguém.

Comment: O Estouro de Pilha ? Nunca participei, fico meio com medo do pessoal me achar pidão demais... Kkkkkk. Mas vou falar com o pessoal lá.