# Uma boa pergunta no Stack Overflow é uma pergunta curta ou longa?

Tags: debate

Essa pergunta se refere a comunidade Stack Overflow em Português, nada do que direi a baixo se refere ao Stack Exchange.

Posso dizer que sou novo no Stack Overflow em Português, venho visualizado os tópicos a pouco mais de 3 meses, observo que algumas perguntas (isso incluí perguntas eu eu fiz) são fechadas e as vezes eu pergunto: Qual o erro dessa pergunta ?

Li o post ["escrever uma pergunta perfeita"](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/), entendi algumas coisas e achei genial a forma como as coisas são colocadas e apresentadas para um bom andamento da plataforma.

Tenho o costume de em toda a comunidade ou site que entro ler os termos e regras, acho que isso é a coisa mais importante e respeitosa que podemos fazer com a comunidade, seu fundador e a equipe de administração, aqui além do que já citei li o ["Que erro cometi ao formular minha pergunta?
"](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/8388/que-erro-cometi-ao-formular-minha-pergunta) mas ainda persiste muito a minha dúvida:

> Qual o erro dessa pergunta ?

É uma questão que muitas vezes me questiono, algumas são óbvias como [essa](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/510260/qual-e-o-erro-da-minha-estrutura/510268#510268) que até tentei ajudar mas acabou sendo fechada.
Como exemplo de questões que não entendo porque são fechadas usarei duas das minhas e uma que salvei.

[Aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/509653/matriz-4x4-em-linguagem-c) tentei estruturar, separar por declarações de variáveis, loop e identifiquei parte por parte como um índice, em negrito detalhando de forma resumida a pergunta.

[Nesta pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/510256/soma-com-vetor-e-ponteiro-em-c) talvez o meu erro tenha sido colocar o código inteiro, mas nada que não pudesse ser editado e resolvido de maneira simples.

[Pergunta realizada hoje](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/510488/integra%C3%A7%C3%A3o-do-front-end-com-banco-de-dados-mysql) Pergunto senhores, o que há de errado nessa questão ? Eu não consigo entender, eu posso estar enganado e por favor me corrijam se eu estiver errado mas parece que os usuários que não tem uma reputação alta não possuem muita visibilidade.

[Essa pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/308452/como-posicionar-este-texto-abaixo-da-tabela) tem +2 e eu não consigo nem entender o que o usuário perguntou, está confusa, mal formatada e mal formulada, porém ele tem uma boa reputação.

Eu estou entendendo a plataforma, quero me adaptar a comunidade e participar mais, acho muito interessante o modo o qual vocês se ajudam, todas as regras e links úteis disponibilizados ajudam muito profissionais e estudantes na área de desenvolvimento. Então a minha pergunta é essa, como deve ser uma pergunta para ser boa ? Longa, curta ou simplesmente bem explicada e resumida ?

Comment: A grande maioria é fechada por falta de um [Mínimo, Completo e Verificável](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) --- Várias perguntas eu comento e oriento, mas as pessoas raramente querem fazer o esforço mínimo de isolar o problema e ficam esperando que "DECIFREMOS" seus códigos inteiros para resolver um problema em uma parte especifica. Falamos disso várias vezes, não acho que nem precise de uma pergunta nova sobre isso, já foi muito debatido, veja: [Guia de sobrevivência](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/8089/guia-de-sobrevivência-do-sopt-versão-curta)

Comment: Não é questão de curta ou longa, é questão de isolar o problema e explicar de forma clara e objetiva, fora que não se deve usar imagens de códigos, exemplo de comentário que costumo fazer: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/510455/problema-ao-iniciar-npm-install#comment937141_510455 ... então basta a pessoa editar conforme as orientações que a pergunta poderá ser reaberta.

Comment: [Nessa pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/510260/112052) a pessoa simplesmente jogou um código (sem dizer o que ele deveria fazer e o que deu errado, ou seja, faltou o já citado MCVE), e quer que a gente adivinhe tudo isso. É menos do que um enunciado (no enunciado pelo menos a gente sabe o que é pra fazer). Só isso já é motivo mais que suficiente pra fechar. Sem contar que tem um erro de digitação (que é outro motivo de fechamento). Sobre as demais perguntas, já foi explicado abaixo.

Comment: Como já dito, o tamanho não define se a pergunta é boa ou não, e sim seu conteúdo. Porém, uma pergunta muito grande pode ser um indício de que há muita encheção de linguiça ou o problema não está isolado ou ela é muito ampla. Assim como uma pergunta muito curta pode ser um indício de que a pergunta não está pouco explicada ou falta um exemplo ou falta o EMCV (Exemplo Mínimo, Completo e Verificável)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

O tamanho nada tem a ver com a qualidade da pergunta. È possível fazer uma boa pergunta que é praticamente só o título ou uma com milhares de linhas.

Pergunta boa é aquela que está [no escopo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), não ser do [tipo que não deve fazer](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask), portanto não pode ser muito subjetiva, estar clara (ter todas informações necessárias para as pessoas entenderem o problema, não é só uma questão de texto que faça sentido), e ter só o que é relevante, não pode ter informação aleatória ou que existe só para que a pessoa não consegue fazer um [exemplo mínimo, completo e verificável](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1186/101). E claro não pode ser uma pergunta que já tenha uma resposta aqui.

Nem precisaria dizer mas uma pergunta que é só um enunciado, curto ou longo, não é sequer uma pergunta.

[Matriz 4x4 em linguagem C](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/509653/101) não tem nada, não sabemos oque a pessoa deseja, pode ter muito erro ali, pode ser que ela viu o que não vimos. Sem **todas** informações não dá para garantir uma boa resposta, só dá para chutar, pode ser um bom chute, mas ainda é um chute.

[Soma com vetor e ponteiro em C](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/510256/101) não está ruim, os negativos talvez sejam porque já tenha feito a pergunta antes mais de uma vez (agora apagadas) e eram sem pé nem cabeça. A pergunta final pode dar a impressão de ser um enunciado, e quase é, então para quem já cansou  de ver lambança fica mais fácil negativar. Não é bom, mas uma avalanche de perguntas ruins também não é. Ajuda o fato do problema não estar bem definido e não fazer muito sentido, talvez fosse o caso de ser fechada porque é ambíguo "a soma deve ser feita com um ponteiro", ninguém sabe o que é isso.

[Integração do Front-end com Banco de Dados MySQL](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/510488/101) não diz como reproduzir o problema, aí surgem respostas esdrúxulas como a postada lá, por isso que esse tipo de pergunta precisa ser fechada logo. Eu negativei porque ela tem [SQL Injection](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/100730/101), é um problema muito mais grave e deveria ser arrumado antes de qualquer coisa. Qualquer código que incentiva isso no site ensina outras pessoas fazerem errado. No passado haviam respostas que ensinavam o certo, mas as pessoas cansaram, quase sempre vem uma resposta que ensina errado e criam um círculo vicioso. O ideal seria alguém comentar, mas novamente, todo mundo cansou de ver esses erros tão básicos e as pessoas não evoluírem depois de ensinadas. Não é bom que seja assim, mas entenda o lado das pessoas estarem cansadas de ver as pessoas fazendo códigos complexos sem o mínimo de estudo do básico, e nada mudar, só piorar.

[Como posicionar este Texto abaixo da Tabela?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/308452/101) quase ninguém entende de Latex aqui então muita coisa fica aberta só porque as pessoas não podem julgar bem.

Comment: Agradeço pelo seu comentário, muita coisa foi esclarecida. Em "Soma com vetor e ponteiro em C" o erro seria a pergunta final "_Como faço para essa soma dar certo utilizando um ponteiro_" ? cheguei a perder certa reputação, mas vou tentar ficar mais atento aos detalhes.
Em "Matriz 4x4" que você citou, pode me dizer o que seria "Sem todas informações não dá para garantir uma boa resposta" ? Naquele caso seria o restante do código ?

Comment: Reforço a parte:  `problema não estar bem definido e não fazer muito sentido, talvez fosse o caso de ser fechada porque é ambíguo "a soma deve ser feita com um ponteiro", ninguém sabe o que é isso`.  No caso da matriz não se fala sobre o erro, não tem detalhes sobre como a soma deve ser feita, porque o código foi feito daquela forma, ela tem premissas que podem existir na sua cabeça mas não está no texto, as pessoas não podem adivinhar. Dá para responder, mas pode não ser a resposta certa. Talvez te falte entendimento do que é preciso para resolver problemas, independente de ser programação.

Comment: Entendo, eu não coloquei o que está errado ou o que aconteceu, o que eu não consegui no caso. Certo, vou ir tentando aprimorar essas questões, o objetivo dessa pergunta é adquirir conhecimento para participar mais da comunidade. Obrigado pelo esclarecimento.