# O fim do Stack Overflow em Português?

Tags: debate, comunidade

Faz alguns anos que a qualidade do conteúdo presente na comunidade vem a cair, gradualmente dia após dia, e desde que observamos isso começamos a agir.

Vários usuários empenhados, de longa data a maioria deles, começaram a colaborar em manter a comunidade saudável e limpa, fazendo:

- Realizando tarefas de análises;
- Fechando, abrindo ou editando perguntas e respostas;
- Comentando, respondendo e perguntando;
- Liderando a comunidade a manter um conteúdo limpo, didático e exemplar.

Não consigo citar todas as inúmeras contribuições memoráveis que temos na comunidade hoje. Graças a elas, milhões de pessoas fluentes em Português aprenderam, estudaram ou foram ensinadas por estes heróis da programação.

Cada usuário colaborador dedicou uma fração de seu tempo para contribuir ativamente com a comunidade e construir o acervo de conhecimento que temos hoje.

Além disso, estes usuários tentaram o máximo manter essa qualidade, que com a chegada do conteúdo mísero, filtraram, removeram e guiaram para alcançarmos uma singularidade.

A comunidade até reuniu um [manual](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/699/faq-da-comunidade) sobre como [sobreviver no SOpt](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/8045/guia-de-sobreviv%C3%AAncia-do-stack-overflow-em-portugu%C3%AAs).

Vou ir direto ao ponto agora, chega de apresentações.

## Não sobraram heróis.

Com o passar destes dias, vários usuários que eram ativos deixaram a comunidade. Usuários com um grande volume de contribuições desistiram, por vários motivos. Alguns saíram ofendidos pelos próprios desinteressados da comunidade e outros simplesmente desistiram de tentar "enxugar o gelo".

A proporção de usuários que ainda se interessam pela comunidade e usuários desinteressados em aprender é absurdamente grande.

Nas filas de análise, conseguimos contar aqueles que colaboram em no máximo ~20 usuários, sem repetir os que estão ativamente lá, mas nas perguntas fechadas conseguimos um número bem maior que esse.

Não temos mais atualizações dos moderadores da comunidade. Sequer se manifestam aqui. A impressão que usuários que já foram ativos têm é que a comunidade está passivamente morrendo.

Das postagens diárias recebidas no site a maioria são fechadas ou removidas pelos usuários que ainda se interessam pela comunidade.

É difícil prever até onde este interesse irá durar nessas circunstâncias.

## E para você que "sobrou"

Me diga, por que você ainda está aqui? O que ainda te motiva e te interessa na comunidade? Como você vê o Stack Overflow em Português nos próximos anos?

Comment: Posso estar falando besteira mas o que ta me soando é: temos um produto onde um grupo enorme de pessoas consome, mas poucos se esforçam pra manter a qualidade, e estes poucos parecem nao ter muita ou nenhuma colaboração dos donos do produto. Ai fica difícil mesmo, "lutar" contra os que só querem consumir sem manter a qualidade(que são a grande maioria) e contra os que mandam.

Comment: 1 - Estou aqui porque tenho esse espirito de contribuir e ajudar aos outros. Replico esse comportamento tanto na minha vida pessoal e profissional quanto aqui no SOpt. Acredito que o eu faço aqui, me ajuda a crescer pessoalmente e profissionalmente. 2 - Como sempre estou buscando aprender e compartilhar coisas novas, isso me motiva a contribuir com SO, pois vejo aqui uma forma direta de compartilhar e de certa forma, ajudar (direta ou indiretamente) alguém. As metas de pontuação e gameficação me deixam um pouco mais empolgado tambem :). 3 - Estou um pouco preocupado com o futuro do site, sendo

Comment: Fico imaginando que em algum momento, terei meu ultimo acesso ao site, assim como já percebo de alguns usuários mais antigos. Alguns que perderam interesse por qualquer motivo pessoal, deixaram de perguntar/responder/moderar o site e isso me deixa um pouco pensativo. Será que teremos usuários novos que serão tão dispostos a crescer na plataforma e meio que continuar o trabalho desses usuarios antigos/moderadores? Será que algum momento isso aqui possa virar uma zona? Pq vejo muita gente nova perguntando, vejo de vez em quando alguém recém chegado na plataforma achar que pode mudar a forma com

Comment: que o site funciona, como ele deve funcionar, que qualquer pergunta feita é válida sem conhecer as características que define uma pergunta como boa...E se sobrar somente esse tipo de usuário? Isso me preocupa com o futuro do SOpt, pois a grande maioria recém chegada não demonstra interesse no site (talvez eu esteja errado), apenas em resolver seus problemas. Claro que enquanto eu estiver aqui, vou ajudar a manter/melhorar/nao deixar piorar a qualidade do site.

Comment: Mudando um pouco o clima de enterro, eu tenho pouco tempo casa, apenas três anos, mas já tive dias divertidos aqui nos Stack Overflow.  Dois momentos que marcaram bastante, um foi uma pergunta sobre algoritmos de classificação onde os ARs improvisamos uma competição para quem implementava a solução mais eficiente com benchmark e tudo. Não venci, mas me diverti muito me senti participando de algo positivo que a comunidade me deu.

Comment: ...Outra vez foi a chuva de negativo que ganhei em menos de cinco segundos, eu havia interpretado equivocadamente uma questão e escrevi uma solução e resposta nada a ver com a pergunta, assim que publiquei deu cinco segundos começou a tempestade -1, foi onde entendi o peso e importância da minhas palavras na comunidade.

Comment: Temos 2 problemas, o primeiro é o numero elevado de usuários nesse ano, que presumo que deve ser por causa de cursos prometendo tornar as pessoas em experts, mas quando estão com dificuldade buscam o site para "suporte pessoal", o que não é o propósito do site, na maximo consequencia, esse problema seria fácil de resolver se não fosse pelo segundo problema, usuários participativos, alguns com score elevado que buscam apoiar o "suporte pessoal" sem perceberem que estão fazendo...

Comment: ... As vezes as perguntas são 3 perguntas em uma, ou muitas vezes é erro de uso ou digitação, o AR (autor da resposta) vê a oportunidade de resolver uma mínima parte da pergunta e acredita de fato que aquilo ali vai ser útil, mas o resto da pergunta ainda não é de fato útil, é suporte pessoal. Volta e meia eu comento, explico, mas tem usuário por ai comentado para fazer o contrário, hoje mesmo comentei para o AP (autor da pergunta) editar a pergunta e fornecer um [mcve], em seguida outro usuário relativamente participativo comentou para o AP postar o **código todo** ...

Comment: ... ou seja, o meu comentário ali já é um enlatado que explica os passos para tirar um bom proveito do site, mas há quem insista no carregar pelas mãos, só que de forma errada. Eu poderia citar uma série de problemas, além desse, mas para resumir, o problema está mais em quem está tentando responder  ou comentando , fazendo as coisas da forma que bem entende, sem considerar entender os ideais da comunidade.

Comment: Comecei a esboçar uma resposta, mas percebi que ela acabaria ficando praticamente igual a [esta](/a/8350/112052), então deixo apenas o link. É triste perceber que desde a data em que que escrevi aquela resposta, as coisas pioraram ainda mais...

Comment: Vejo o mesmo em algumas questões no SOEn, uma grande quantidade de perguntas com má qualidade de usuários que recém criaram a conta, isso provavelmente está ocorrendo devido a grande quantidade de pessoas entrando na área, com cursos prometendo milagres em poucos meses, pessoas desesperadas por respostas sem nem tentar seguir o [MCV (Mínimo, completo e verificável)](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1186/como-criar-um-exemplo-m%c3%adnimo-completo-e-verific%c3%a1vel).

Comment: Aqueles eventos da SE de 2019 que fizeram vários moderadores da rede renunciarem em massa me desmotivaram um monte de contribuir com o SOpt ou com qualquer coisa na SE. Também não tenho mais o tempo que tinha outrora.

Comment: @VictorStafusa muitos estão lentamente "renunciando" a plataforma desde então, sendo menos ativos, se importando menos com a comunidade. Haverá uma hora que não haverá mais moderadores ou usuários proativos.

Comment: A necessidade mais primária do desenvolvedor (em desenvolvimento) parece não ter como ser suprida nessa plataforma, que prima pelo desenvolvedor mais experiente. Esse, pelo contrário, passa de vez em quando por aqui, uma vez que não precisa da plataforma. Quem necessita não é atendido por regras da plataforma. Há um equívoco claro na gestão do negócio.

Comment: @Daniel o pessoal confunde muito o SOpt como uma plataforma de help-desk, ajuda pessoal ou qualquer coisa que force um "desenvolvedor experiente" limpar a caca dos outros. Não é este o propósito do SOpt, nunca foi. Se um desenvolvedor, mesmo que iniciante, não consiga transformar sua pergunta ou dúvida em algo canônico, didático e que possa ajudar outros usuários, **ele nunca se tornará um programador de verdade*.

Comment: A maioria do conteúdo de help desk não serve pra nada senão para o próprio autor da pergunta. Conteúdos dispensáveis que dispensam a atenção dos desenvolvedores experientes. Não estamos aqui para ajudar uma só pessoa.

Comment: Não se pode confundir "inexperiente" com "descompromissado com a plataforma". Um completo "analfabeto de programação" pode fazer perguntas excelentes e muito bem-vindas no site (tem muitas, há perguntas fundamentais com assuntos para leigos). Problema são os que vem só resolver a tarefas pessoais e específicas e não cumprem o mínimo necessário (inclui usuários exímios em programação e que também não servem para a plataforma, temos casos). Inexperientes sempre vão se dar bem aqui, desde que dentro da finalidade do site. O filtro é a qualidade e utilidade da postagem, e não o grau de expertise.

Comment: Equivoco claro se dá ao desprezar a história o acervo do site em busca de um solucionar imediato através do uso equivocado das ferramentas oferecidas ao usuário. Uma vasta gama de tópicos considerados como fundamentais para programação já foram esmiuçados ao longo da existência do Stack Overflow em Português. Bastando a boa vontade do usuário ler a documentação do site e utilizar a barra de pesquisa ou sua engine de busca favorita antes de formular uma pergunta.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Essa publicação é continuação do ["O fim do Stack Overflow em Português?"](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/8786/o-fim-do-stack-overflow-em-portugu%c3%aas).

Pouco tempo se passou desde a publicação, a percepção hoje é um pouco diferente. Como tudo no mundo se transforma e muda, essa comunidade não foi exceção, ela também mudou, se fragmentou, e por consequência, hoje temos uma comunidade fragmentada, distribuída em opiniões sobre a própria comunidade e movidos pelo acreditamos estar "certo" e o que é "errado".

De um lado do muro, nós encontramos pessoas que buscam ajuda, de forma irresponsável e desleixada, com conteúdo medíocre e desqualificado até mesmo para o mercado de trabalho, e com pessoas que tendem alimentar essa necessidade de suporte pessoal com respostas de mesmo nível ou pior, induzindo o perguntador a continuar e petular na contramão do objetivo original deste site.

Do outro lado, temos um pessoal arrogante, chato e tóxico, que defendem a qualidade abrangente como se fosse uma religião, rejeitando os pedidos de ajuda pessoais para aqueles que estão desesperados e mal conseguem elaborar uma pergunta legível. São as pessoas que estão preocupadas em seguir os objetivos primitivos do site, em manter o respeito e conhecimento como os principais pilares da comunidade.

Um lado está em desacordo com o outro. Lendo os dois parágrafos acima você irá entender em qual lado você está.

O resultado disso é um ambiente desconfortável, arrogante e hostil. Esse ambiente é refletido em ambos os lados. A consequência disso é que usuários estão abandonando a comunidade em massa. Não existe mais aquela vontade de "pertencer" à algum lugar que um dia foi a "aba fixa" de muitas pessoas.

Tantos usuários veteranos e potenciais novos usuários abandonaram a comunidade em vista de tudo isso.

Algo comum entre os lados é que ambos se sentem desamparados pela Stack Exchange, que por muito tempo se manteve em silêncio em virtude à estes inúmeros conflitos. Cada desabafo e cada resposta aos desabafos que surgem no Meta é um conflito, e nunca esteve tão frequente até uns meses atrás.

Notaram que as reclamações e desabafos diminuiram mas o conteúdo ruim permaneceu? O silêncio é uma das últimas etapas deste processo.

Ambas as partes permanecem em silêncio, e eu não consigo ver um futuro favorável para nenhuma delas nessa comunidade.

Comment: Concordo com esse post, inclusive me considero de um dos lados dessa sua conclusão, existem perguntas realmente ruins sendo feitas, no entanto existem perguntas legitimas de novatos sendo crucificadas por não cumprirem com os padrões extremamente altos do site, por muitas vezes tentei ajudar algumas pessoas iniciantes e acabei sendo negativado (e o negativador nem mesmo se prestou a dar um comentário explicando a negativação) o que me fez aos poucos acabar desistindo de contribuir, já que de certa forma estava perdendo um tempo  elaborando uma resposta que no fim me deixaria com menos pontos

Comment: @LucasMiranda já falamos sobre isso aqui várias vezes, sobre que uma boa resposta para uma pergunta ruim também é uma resposta ruim. Devemos incentivar os usuários à melhorar suas perguntas, fechando-as e apontando os erros, para que melhore. Respondendo elas irá enxugar gelo e o OP irá entender que está tudo certo com a pergunta dele. Além disso, downvote não é necessariamente ruim: é um indicativo que sua publicação tem problemas e que você pode melhorar ela.

Answer (score 6):

Sinto que o problema na comunidade reflete um desafio humano fundamental: a qualidade dos relacionamentos éticos. Aqui está uma sugestão para aprimorar a abordagem:

**Acolher** todas as perguntas que estejam dentro do escopo da comunidade, evitando qualquer julgamento, linguagem ofensiva ou retaliação. Devemos receber cada questionamento com cordialidade, oferecendo orientação simples e apoio.

**Responder** com paciência, educação e orientação, lembrando que ninguém está obrigado a fazer parte disso. É importante reconhecer que, muitas vezes, pessoas com grande experiência e conhecimento podem, inicialmente, mostrar impaciência, intolerância e arrogância. Isso pode ser um reflexo inconsciente, mas comum, entre aqueles que estão intelectualmente evoluindo (em qualquer área de conhecimento). No entanto, à medida que superam essa fase do "pseudo-sábio", a humildade, a tolerância e a paciência tendem a ressurgir. É nessa etapa que vemos o desenvolvimento de indivíduos que exibem verdadeira SABEDORIA com HUMILDADE, e é nesse momento que começamos a admirar, seguir e apoiar essas pessoas como verdadeiros fãs.

Pode parecer que estamos atualmente carentes dessas qualidades, mas é reconfortante saber que elas estão presentes em nossa comunidade. Vamos continuar a crescer e evoluir, pois nossa comunidade é vasta e está aprendendo com seus próprios erros e sucessos.

Obrigado.

Comment: gostaria de contribuir com sua mensagem aproveitando que você recebeu um downvote sem feedback. Essa falta de feedback ao dar downvote é justamente o que os **memes do StackOverflow** criticam. Isso também atrapalha na hora de melhorar a mensagem que recebeu -1.

Comment: Por isso mesmo, dei upvote e uma nova oportunidade para você, mesmo não sabendo quem te deu -1 ou porquê. Se alguém quer me fazer mudar de ideia **que me explique**.

Comment: @EduApps a ideia do downvote no site é uma ação democrática que o conteúdo é ruim e que pode ser melhorado. No meta exclusivamente, é indicado para quando você "não concorda com o conteúdo", desde que algumas postagens são opinativas. Ref: https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/652/voto-negativo-sem-justificativa-%c3%a9-v%c3%a1lido

Comment: Sim, é esse o ponto. Pode ser melhorado. Mas isso é entendível. O que se não entende é "O quê pode ser melhorado".

Comment: Concordo em gênero, número e grau com o @EduApps . Achei a resposta muito boa. Não consigo ver pontos negativos nela. Isso foi uma das coisas que me afastou dessa comunidade. Acho que o downvote deveria vir pelo menos com uma justificativa mínima com poucos caracteres (uns 30 ou 40 no máximo).

Answer (score 2):

Sou um usuário extremamente novo aqui na comunidade do SOpt (comparado aos demais) e tenho notado uma desaceleração no interesse e na participação dos usuários. Eu entendo que existem diversas razões que podem ter contribuído para isso, como o surgimento de novas plataformas de aprendizado e possíveis fatores específicos da comunidade que possam estar desencorajando alguns usuários.

### *Minha humilde visão como um iniciante na comunidade.*

Tenho um grande interesse em contribuir com a comunidade. No entanto, às vezes é difícil para mim contribuir plenamente devido às restrições de privilégios.

Como novo usuário do SOpt, tenho experimentado as dificuldades de interagir com perguntas e respostas. Por vezes, minhas sugestões de edição demoram para ser avaliadas, e infelizmente, como um usuário iniciante, tenho apenas um limite de quatro sugestões. Entendo que essas restrições existem para garantir a qualidade do conteúdo e prevenir abusos.

Apesar desses obstáculos, estou determinado a contribuir para a comunidade. Sempre que possível, tento responder perguntas que conheço e estou em constante aprendizado com as respostas de outros usuários. Apesar de não poder votar para fechar perguntas ruins etc...

Na minha visão, seria muito interessante incentivar novos usuários a contribuírem para a comunidade... para realizar uma pergunta na plataforma, o usuário deve antes contribuir com a comunidade respondendo alguma pergunta (ou realizando uma votação para pergunta ruim ou boa). Essa exigência pode ajudar a aumentar a participação dos usuários e a criar um ambiente mais colaborativo, será que assim evitaria os *help desk*? só vem para sugar e não contribui com nada rsrs.

Claro isso não seria flores, abriria margem para respostas ruins em perguntas boas ou UP votes (não sei se é o nome certo) para perguntas ruins. Mas oque eu quero passar é essa visão de quem é novo e poderia contribuir, o mundo sempre está em ciclos e virá perguntas boas ainda, levando em consideração a evolução da tecnologia como por exemplo: **Inteligência artificial e aprendizado de máquina**, tenho certeza que surgirá muitas e muitas perguntas boas aqui para ajudar nesse crescimento rsrsrs

A comunidade do SO é um ciclo constante de aprendizado e compartilhamento de conhecimento. Novos usuários trazem novas perguntas e desafios, e veteranos da comunidade contribuem com suas experiências e soluções. Essa troca contínua de informações e perspectivas é fundamental para o crescimento da comunidade.

### *Quanto ao futuro da comunidade?*

É difícil prever o que acontecerá, mas acredito que a comunidade pode se adaptar e evoluir para atender às necessidades dos usuários ativos (ou novos ativos). Talvez mudanças na forma como a comunidade é gerenciada ou novas iniciativas para atrair e engajar usuários possam ser consideradas. Mas, em última análise, o sucesso da comunidade dependerá da capacidade dos usuários ativos de se envolverem e colaborarem de forma construtiva para esse novo ciclo que passamos.

Obrigado pela atenção e espero poder aprender e contribuir mais com a comunidade!

Comment: Contribuições são sempre bem-vindas quando estão de fato contribuindo para os pilares da comunidade: qualidade, abrangência e conhecimento. Algumas medidas que limitam os novos usuários foram criadas porque muitos usuários estavam abusando de recursos que criava uma massiva quantia de publicações ruins, e ficava muito pesado para comunidade lidar com essa montanha de conteúdo. Muitas das vezes só tentar direcionar o novato para aprender como o site funciona, tentar ensinar e explicar o site é só perda de tempo, alguns nos chamam de tóxicos e continuam a postar asneira no site.

Comment: O que muitos consideram "sucesso" nós já alcançamos: ter conteúdo de qualidade e ser um grande acervo de conhecimento confiável de programação. Claro que para manter esse título precisamos continuar com o filtro de conteúdo e jamais sermos considerados um "helpdesk". Para o sucesso continuar, novos conteúdos "bons" devem continuar sendo publicados, esse é o incentivo.

Comment: Inteligência artificial e aprendizado de máquina não está no escopo do site, aqui nós tratamos especificamente de linguagens de programação. O [pt.so] é integrante de uma rede Q&As temáticos. a [Stack Exchange](https://stackexchange.com/sites) onde o [Artificial Intelligence](https://ai.stackexchange.com/) é site especializado em aprendizado de máquina e inteligência artificial.

Comment: Quanto a participação com novas perguntas é um tema complicado pois a maioria das perguntas que recebemos já foram anteriormente feitas bastando ao usuário pesquisar direto no site ou através de um mecanismo de buscas. Quando se trata de uma verdadeira nova pergunta em geral não pode ser aproveitada. São poucas as perguntas genuinamente novas, então é natural que a entradas de diminua onde a maior parte das ações os usuários ativos sejam apenas comentam apontando links de conteúdos relacionados e/ou orientam no uso do site.

Comment: Conforme o cenário de linguagens se modifica ou se renova então o fluxo de usuários perguntando e respondendo aumenta, num cenário mais estável o fluxo de usuários perguntando e respondendo tende a diminuir. A nossa grande clientela do site são os usuário que diariamente e incessantemente nos chegam  através de engines de busca visando pesquisa nosso acervo.

Comment: Em resumo quando se fala em "fim do Stack Overflow em português" existem dois tipos de usuários. O primeiro tipo é o mais óbvio, é usuário que não faz pesquisa, não contribui com a comunidade, polui o nosso acervo, hostiliza a qualquer que tente o orientar e só produz conteúdo qualidade baixa, para esse  usuário o "fim do Stack Overflow em português" se dá quando a comunidade o enquadra e o mostra que aqui não pode fazer o que quiser da forma que quiser e bem entender pois o sarrafo é mais alto, a exigência por qualidade é contínua e constante e esse usuário não está capacitado usar o site.

Comment: O outro tipo de usuário é aquele que pesquisa diligentemente, é participativo na comunidade, preserva e contribui com o acervo do site, orienta virtuosamente a comunidade, produz conteúdo de alta qualidade e aceita criticas quando merecidas. Para esse tipo de usuário "fim do Stack Overflow em português" significa poucos usuários votando e classificando conteúdos e poucos usuários fazendo moderação comunitária.

Comment: Todos gostamos de perguntar responder e ganharmos uns pontos de reputação porém com o fluxo de perguntas genuinamente novas é naturalmente baixo os pontos estão escassos implicando que os usuários mais novos não se dedicam as tarefas moderativas, pois essa não dão pontos ou quando dão pontos esses tem um limite. E esse é o cenário de "fim do Stack Overflow em português" a que a pergunta se refere e o espaço de respostas está aberto para o debate de propostas e soluções a esse cenário que espero ter conseguido o descrever.

Answer (score 2):

O SOpt me ajudou muito no início da carreira e sou muito grato. Infelizmente, me afastei da comunidade por diversos pontos negativos que via e sofria. Esses motivos que me afastaram, são citados de forma recorrente por vários outros usuários que passam pelos mesmos problemas que passei. Inclusive, me afastei em uma época que precisava muito. Precisei começar a recorrer a outras fontes, outras comunidades... Talvez isso tenha feito bem pra mim, mesmo que o caminho tenha sido mais árduo.

Eu não era um membro de ajudar muito, devido a minha inexperiência. Mas eu participava ativamente da comunidade e gostava muito daqui. Era minha referência. Infelizmente hoje, a meu ver, a comunidade morreu e vive de um belo passado e da sua grande base de dados deixada.

As tão sonhadas reputações, que eram buscadas incansavelmente pelos usuários, morreram com os seus donos (conosco) e hoje servem apenas de enfeite para seus respectivos totens e para menções em perfis de redes sociais e páginas de perfis.

O SOpt é uma plataforma que ficará na memória de muitos usuários. Muito mais pelas boas lembranças e também pela grande ajuda que a plataforma prestou e ainda presta, devido ao seu enorme banco de perguntas e respostas, para várias pessoas.

Porém, sinto que a plataforma está chegando ao fim, principalmente pela chegada das IA's que, se utilizadas com sabedoria, praticamente dispensa a utilização dessa plataforma aqui e deixa o SOpt apenas como base para conferência, não mais para referência.

A plataforma deixa como legado, uma bela e extensa base de dados e seu tópicos ficam como resultados de pesquisas no Google e similares, para o todo e eterno sempre ♥

Quem viveu, viveu. Quem não viveu, não viverá mais.

Comment: Só uma observação, tenho lido que a IA vai substituir a rede (e outros sites), mas estamos longe disso, até agora não existe IA aberta que consiga fazer programação nem básica. Mal e mal sai algum snippet de código, mas com erros crassos, quando acerta é coincidência. A IA só vai substituir o humano ruim nessa parte de código e texto, o profissional ao menos medíocre pode ficar sossegado. Tem áreas que a IA está boa, como voz e imagem, pq isso não é conhecimento de nicho. Texto ainda é só  gerador de fake news, e código é comparável ao dos 'aventureiros' na área, não acredito que mude tão já.

Comment: Normalmente se eu comentar isso com outras redes o pessoal vai tacar pedra (justamente o pessoal que não tem condição de avaliar a IA), mas aqui no site ainda comento, pq tem um pouco mais de filtro de qualidade pra quem participa, e tem gente que leva a área mais a sério, então a observação não é totalmente perdida. De qq forma já faz uns anos que a rede está fadada a diluir e sumir, mas por outras razões que não vem ao caso agora, até para não tirar o foco do seu post. Talvez fosse melhor se pusessem só os de programação em read-only, mas lembrando que a rede tem outros temas ainda em alta.