# O Stackoverflow PT em 2023, em números

Tags: debate

Eu estava fazendo umas queries na base de dados do Stackoveflor PT, e aproveitei para tirar algumas métricas. Para quem quiser ver todas as queries, eis aqui o link: [https://data.stackexchange.com/pt/](https://data.stackexchange.com/pt/query/1732177/status-questions-2023)

A ideia era olhar para a qualidade das nossas perguntas. Todos temos notado a enorme quantidade de perguntas com pontuação negativa e fechadas, mas, o quanto isso representa do conteúdo produzido no SO Pt em 2023?

Com essas queries, é possível identificar algumas coisas interessantes. Primeiro, o resultado da query que mostra o total de perguntas agrupadas pelo score, ou pontuação:

| Total de questões | Pontuação |
| --- | --- |
| 3 | -6 |
| 10 | -5 |
| 54 | -4 |
| 130 | -3 |
| 239 | -2 |
| 235 | -1 |
| 449 | 0 |
| 60 | 1 |
| 20 | 2 |
| 16 | 3 |
| 18 | 4 |
| 15 | 5 |
| 5 | 6 |
| 1 | 7 |
| 1 | 8 |
| 1 | 11 |

Temos um total de 1257 questões este ano até o momento. Com outras queries, é possível chegar a outros totais:

- 1257 perguntas em 2023, incluindo fechadas e deletadas
- 1120 com score "não positivo", seja, menor ou igual a zero = 89,1%
- 671 com score negativo = 53,4%
- 586 com score maior ou igual a zero = 46,6%
- 271 perguntas fechadas = 21,6%
- 48 perguntas "auto respondidas" pelo próprio OP = 8,19%

Podemos notar que mais da metade das perguntas tem score negativo. Note que, "score" é a soma entre votos positivos e negativos.
Isso mostra em números bem claramente que a qualidade das nossas perguntas não anda das melhores, o que é refletidos pelo que nós vemos todos os dias: uma grande quantidade de perguntas fechadas/negativadas.

Isso é mais um post informativo para pensarmos e discutirmos sobre esses números. Outras queries e números são bem-vindos.

Comment: Não sei se eu que não entendi direito, mas qual seria o debate de fato? Estatísticas agregadas usualmente [já são publicadas](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/estat%c3%adsicas) (e do ano todo). Estamos no começo de 2023 ainda, e os critérios usados me parecem um pouco aleatórios. Negativos e qualidade, por exemplo, já estão extensivamente debatidos em outras postagens. Seria interessante se pudesse esclarecer melhor a relevância dos dados que escolheu e/ou qual é foco que está propondo quando fala em "pensar e discutir sobre os números", até para evitar respostas aleatórias.

Comment: O que exatamente vc quer discutir? Se for sobre qualidade em geral, já tem vários posts (alguns até que recentes, inclusive), e aí só iríamos repetir o que já foi discutido. Essencialmente, a situação não mudou (usuários não lêem a Central de Ajuda, a gente comenta mas não adianta, postam a pergunta de qq jeito, a SE não faz nada pra ajudar, sobrou pouca gente pra ajudar na moderação/curadoria, etc). Talvez tenha piorado, mas as causas básicas ainda são as mesmas. Não sei se tem mais o que acrescentar, além do que já foi dito anteriormente...

Comment: @hkotsubo a ideia é mostrar números, é algo mais concreto que "a qualidade caiu" ou "a qualidade das perguntas é ruim". E até para se questionar: se 89,1% (com score zero ou negativo) das perguntas não são "consideradas úteis", o SO está atendendo ao seu propósito? Não é pq temos uma tendência de pessoas que querem tudo pronto, usuário de chatgpt, etc, que estamos indo no caminho errado, mas será que é relevante continuar a enxugar gelo? Vale o esforço de fazer a moderação/curadoria pra salvar 11% das perguntas? Sinceramente eu não sei! É cansativo e frustrante

Comment: É como querer manter o orkut vivo quando as pessoas queriam ir pra algo diferente, tentar manter a midia física quando o digital já é a preferência, entende? Não é uma questão de certo ou errado, é uma questão de tendência, e tentar manter a qualidade do SO Pt é tão cansativo que às vezes, principalmente olhando para esses números, me faz refletir se vale a pena. A base de conhecimento acululada através de anos é inegavelmente útil, mas de uns tempos pra cá me parece que é só isso com algumas excessões

Comment: Atualmente, o site não cumpre mais seu propósito, só vale pelo conteúdo antigo. Assumindo, claro, que ainda é o mesmo objetivo inicial (o tal repositório de conhecimento sobre programação, etc), pois a SE deixou bem claro que não se importa mais com qualidade, apenas quantidade (**só falta ela admitir publicamente, mas todas as ações dela já confirmam isso**). Muitos decidiram que não vale a pena enxugar gelo, os poucos que restam eu não sei qto tempo vão continuar. É cansativo e frustrante, e não sei se tem solução (na verdade tem sim, mas a SE não está disposta a fazer).

Comment: Ou seja, tudo discussões que já tivemos antes :-) Compartilho da sua preocupação e aprecio seu esforço em levantar os números, mas deu uma sensação de "_já vi esse filme e sei que o final não é bom_". Exemplo: https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8786/112052 (só pra citar uma discussão similar e relativamente recente)

Comment: *"não se importa mais com qualidade, apenas quantidade"* isso é muito triste, pq não é só a questão de qualidade, é também de ensinar as pessoas a pesquisar, tentar, serem também autodidatas, etc... é uma tendência de profissionais pouco focados nisso, eles querem tudo pronto e pouco esforço, e isso não se aprende com quantidade, apenas com qualidade

Comment: "*eles querem tudo pronto e pouco esforço*" - Pois é, o SO era um dos sites que mais tinha potencial pra tentar reverter essa situação, mas em vez disso, decidiu abraçar o helpdesk pra inflar os números e ser comprado. Não adianta, se a maioria quer algo e vc quer números, compensa mais agradar a maioria. E no caso, a maioria quer helpdesk e respostas rápidas e fáceis (e não necessariamente certas ou com qualidade). Triste, mas é como o nosso mundo está hoje em dia, não só na nossa área, mas em tudo