# JS, CSS e HTML executáveis no corpo da pergunta ou resposta

Tags: suporte, faq, formatação, stack-snippets

Em qualquer dos nossos sites que envolvem programação, [criar um exemplo mínimo, completo e verificável](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) é o melhor jeito de conseguir uma boa resposta para sua pergunta. Adoramos sites como o [JSFiddle](http://www.jsfiddle.com) porque eles permitem que você possa se referir a um código executável, quando quiser demonstrar seu problema ou solução.

Infelizmente, o uso destes sites externos traz alguns problemas:

1. Se o link quebrar, o post se torna quase inútil
2. Se o código não estiver presente no texto, os leitores teriam que visitar outro site para entender totalmente o conteúdo
3. Além disso, como o código não faz parte do markdown do post, alterações nele não entram para o histórico de edições do post

Com todos estes problemas envolvendo o uso de sites externos, a comunidade do SE em geral chegou a decidir pelo bloqueio de posts que contivessem apenas links para o JSFiddle, sem apresentar o código também no corpo do post. Isso causava um trabalho extra para todos que quisessem fazer usso da ferramenta.

Então decidimos criar nossa própria ferramenta para inserir código executável nos posts! Estamos lançando o "Stack Snippets", presente no Stack Overflow e todos os outros sites relacionados a programação.

### Vamos ter outras linguagens?

Por enquanto, apenas HTML, CSS e JavaScript são suportados porque estas são as linguagens que faziam uso de serviços externos com mais frequência. Além disso, elas são executadas no lado do cliente, sendo mais fácil dar suporte. Linguagens do lado do servidor necessitariam de mudanças significativas de infraestrutura, se quisermos implementar algo similar. Por enquanto não faz parte dos planos, mas podemos reconsiderar no futuro.

### E quanto ao JSFiddle?

**Você pode continuar usando o JSFiddle, se preferir**. O JSFiddle, e outros sites similares, tem um monte de funcionalidades que ainda não implementamos. Basta lembrar que as regras normais para links ainda valem: certifique-se de copiar o trecho de código relevante para dentro do post, para que ele esteja sempre disponível.

Decidimos implementar nossa própria versão pelas razões citadas anteriormente:

- **Não é mais necessário copiar-e-colar o código para o post**. Tudo é inserido no corpo do post, então o histórico de edições e os diffs funcionam sem problemas.
- **Não é mais necessário visitar outro site para conseguir uma resposta**. É sempre melhor quando a pergunta e a(s) resposta(s) estão na mesma página.
- **Nós hospedamos, nós garantimos**. Levamos a performance e a disponibilidade dos nossos sites muito a sério, e assim podemos ter certeza de que os trechos de código vão estar sempre disponíveis.

### Brinquem à vontade

Queremos ver como vocês vão utilizar essa nova ferramenta, e contamos com seu feedback:

- Se encontrar algum bug, ou quiser dar sua opinião sobre os Stack Snippets, use o nosso [Meta](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com), com a tag [stack-snippets](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/stack-snippets)
- Se quiser ver como funciona, temos um [sandbox no Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/239456/stack-snippets-sandbox-try-it-out-here)
- Se você acha que algum site, em particular, também devia ter Stack Snippets, faça um pedido de [novo-recurso](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/novo-recurso) no respectivo Meta. Se a comunidade apoiar, habilitaremos lá também.

Já existem alguns [exemplos sensacionais no Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/62577/bouncing-stacking-boxes). Compartilhem outros exemplos, ou *criem os seus*! Divirtam-se!

[Retorne para o índice da FAQ](/q/699)

Comment: Só o Meta.SOen tem snippets habilitados?

Comment: Fui conferir, e o meta do CodeReview tem os snippets habilitados. O Meta.SE também tem. É só digitar no console do site em questão: `StackExchange.options.snippets.enabled` e mostra o status. Teve algum *reasoning* para deixar nosso meta sem snippets?

Comment: @brasofilo eles provavelmente pediram. Se quiserem aqui, só pedir

Comment: Ok, *false by default*, se quiser, pede.

Comment: @brasofilo isso. É o padrão com todo recurso que envolva deixar o carregamento mais lento.

Comment: legal o recurso.

Comment: Show de bola! Parabéns!

Comment: Muito bom........

Comment: Seria possível executar PHP também? caso fosse seria ótimo! é sério.

Comment: realmente, ajudara em muito. Ja tinha visto isso no SOen, e me perguntava como tinha feito, hehe

Comment: Esse tipo de "artigo" pode ser postado em "Perguntas"?

Comment: @LucasHenrique Como assim? Aqui no Meta?

Comment: @Gabe exato. Não estou questionando, adorei o artigo, dei +1 e até favoritei. Porém acredito que não tenhamos um blog, certo? Dê também uma olhada na minha mais nova pergunta:http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/2365/2692

Comment: @LucasHenrique Alguns anúncios são feitos no [blog](http://blog.stackexchange.com), outros são feitos no [Meta Stack Exchange](http://meta.stackexchange.com) (ou [Meta Stack Overflow](http://meta.stackoverflow.com)). Nem todas as perguntas nos Metas precisam ser "perguntas", várias aqui no MSOpt não são. Alguns são anúncios, como esse. O MSOpt tem mais desses porque não podemos fazer uso do blog, por conta do Português. Talvez um dia tenhamos um blog próprio, mas até lá o nosso Meta atende muito bem.

Comment: @Gabe sonhar é algo muito bom. Vamos lutar! :)

Answer (score 9):

## Como funciona?

Com o Stack Snippets, um simples trecho de código:

<kbd>[image: código normal]</kbd>

Se torna um trecho de código *executável*:

<kbd>[image: Stack Snippet!]</kbd>

O código será executado quando o botão "Run code snippet" for pressionado:

<kbd>[image: Resultado da execução]</kbd>

## Como criar um Stack Snippet

Os Stack Snippets podem ser utilizados tanto em perguntas quanto em respostas. Na janela de edição do Markdown, há um novo botão que você pode clicar parar abrir o editor do Stack Snippets.

<kbd>[image: Botão de criação do Stack Snippet]</kbd>

Você então pode inserir o seu HTML, CSS ou JavaScript, de acordo com seu problema, ou solução:

<kbd>[image: Editor do Stack Snippet]</kbd>

Quando estiver tudo certo com seu código, clique em "Inserir no Post", logo abaixo do editor e pronto! Você pode testar seu trecho de código, ou voltar ao editor, direto da tela de preview do seu post.

<kbd>[image: Escolha o que fazer com seu trecho de código]</kbd>

Se você estiver respondendo a um post que contém um Snippet, é possível inserir uma versão modificada do original na sua resposta - basta clicar em "Copiar trecho para a resposta".

## Formatação em Markdown

Uma das melhores características dos Stack Snippets é que eles são inseridos **como blocos normais de código** no seu Markdown.

<kbd>[image: Blocos.... NORMAIS!]</kbd>

Isso significa que eles são automaticamente compatíveis com nosso sistema de revisões, diffs, e qualquer cliente da nossa API, incluindo nossos [aplicativos](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/01/stack-exchange-for-android-is-here) [móveis](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/05/stack-exchange-for-iphone-is-here).

A execução dos blocos de código é disparada por alguns comentários HTML que não são renderizados pelo Markdown. Você pode, inclusive, editar o código pelo editor normal, e o trecho continuará executável.

## Os Stack Snippets são seguros?

**Sim. Tanto quanto a web é segura**. Você está tão seguro quanto estaria ao navegar em qualquer site com JavaScript habilitado. Dito isso, os snippets vão *executar código no seu navegador* e, portanto, você deve ter cuidado ao rodar código de outros usuários.

Nós isolamos os snippets de forma a bloquear acesso aos seus dados no Stack Exchange:

- Usamos **iframes HTML5 em sandbox**, como prevenção contra diversos tipos de ataques.
- Nós **renderizamos os snippets em um domínio externo** (stacksnippets.net), para garantir que a regra de same-origin não seja aplicada, impedindo que os snippets possam acessar suas sessões e cookies.

Como todos os outros aspectos no nosso site, os Stack Snippets são **controlados pela comunidade**. Snippets são automaticamente desabilitados em posts com muitos votos contra (-3 no site principal, -8 no Meta) já que é possível criar códigos mal-intencionados, mesmo que inofensivos, como loops ou pop-ups infinitos. Se você vir um trecho de código que acredita que deveria ser desabilitado, **vote contra**. Se vir algo que é intencionalmente nocivo (como uma tentativa de phishing), **sinalize o post para a moderação**.