# Um FAQ para os Stack Snippets

Tags: debate, status-pronto, pergunta-específica, formatação, stack-snippets

Estou na dúvida se a pergunta **[JS, CSS e HTML executáveis no corpo da pergunta ou resposta](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2115)** serve como ítem do nosso [FAQ da Comunidade](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/699/faq-da-comunidade) aqui no Meta.

O post é um anúncio oficial da Stack Exchange e ao mesmo tempo contém o tutorial de como usar o novo recurso. Até pensei em remover o tutorial da pergunta e passar para uma resposta wiki, mas o problema é exatamente o Anúncio e de ter a tag [debate](/questions/tagged/debate): também pensei em trocar isso para [suporte](/questions/tagged/suporte), mas de novo não parece muito correto, nem tampouco aplicar [proposta-para-faq](/questions/tagged/proposta-para-faq) nela.

Acho que precisamos de um meta-post para onde sinalizar os usuários que não estão usando o recurso corretamente. Talvez como uma resposta dentro de [Como devemos formatar perguntas e respostas](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1084)? Uma nova P&R? O que fazer com o anúncio, deixar como está e duplicar aquele tutorial?

Comment: Anúncio é uma coisa datada, acho que podemos sim deixar só as explicações e transformar em faq.

Comment: Concordo com o @bfavaretto

Comment: @bfavaretto, você diz no FAQ da Comunidade para sinalizar e pedir a transformação da pergunta em Wiki... não sinalizei, mas, bueno, quando puder revisar, legal!

Comment: Parece que está bom agora. Transformei a pergunta em CW também.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, [image].
Agora é só indicar aos incautos como organizar corretamente seu código:
[image]
<sup><sub><sup>*PS: sem qualquer afiliação e sem nenhuma relação com a marca que aparece acima*</sup></sub></sup>

Comment: Poderíamos trocar o ícone do editor por um *donut*, assim todos iriam clicar com certeza.

Comment: @utluiz: Pois é, estava até pensando nisso "o que será que tem os ícones que causa a confusão?" Porque clicar num e não no outro?