# Como publicar código PHP?

Tags: suporte

Como eu poderia publicar código PHP?
A forma correta é pela amostra de código?

Pergunto porque vejo muito código feito pela ferramenta de CSS, HTML e javascript, mas ao mesmo tempo já me mostraram que não pode, na verdade me mandaram um link mostrando a ferramenta de CSS, HTML e javascript e quem mandou foi meio grosseiro, mas cada um tem seus problemas.

Comment: Normalmente se usa a formatação de código, e só. Isso pode ser feito para HTML/CSS/JS também, pois é algo genérico, algo que só faz o realce de sintaxe e mais nada. Apenas se você quiser um exemplo **executável**, no próprio *browser* mesmo (i.e. inline na pergunta/resposta), é que faz sentido se usar o Stack Snippets.

Comment: Era isso que eu queria saber! Coloca na resposta para eu marcar?

Comment: Ok, deixa só eu dar uma pesquisada pra ver se não é duplicata, e então eu respondo.

Comment: Fui um pouco rude sim, desculpe. Me deixei impressionar pelo fato que dá pra ver que o código não é auto-executável, e fiz o comentário brusco sem necessidade, era só colocar o link e tudo ok. Quando topar com esse tipo de comentário é só sinalizar como "rude/ofensivo".

Comment: Agora entendi o seu problema, é algo que eu estava tentando entender o porque ocorre e até criei uma questão no http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/247424/198279 - Eu realmente não entendo, se é preguiça de ler ou a ferramenta é pouco intuitiva, está mais do que óbvio que o StackSnippet é pra executar exemplos html/css/js e as pessoas insistem em usar ele. Talvez você poderia me dizer? O icone do StackSnippet é mais intuitivo? Pensei em sugerir um icone escrito JS/CSS ou algo assim :p

Answer (score 13, accepted):

O principal objetivo ao se publicar código é que ele seja compreensível e legível. A ferramenta "Amostra de código <pre> <code> Ctrl-K" serve justamente para estilizar o código e tentar aplicar [realce de sintaxe](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/33/215).

Basta selecionar o código com o mouse e pressionar o ícone `{ }` conforme a imagem, ou usar o atalho de teclado:

[image: Captura da toolbar]

Por exemplo, isso:

<?php

$os = array("Mac", "NT", "Irix", "Linux"); 
if (in_array("Irix", $os)) { 
    echo "Tem Irix";
}
if (in_array("mac", $os)) { 
    echo "Tem mac";
}

?>

É menos legível que isso:

```
<?php

$os = array("Mac", "NT", "Irix", "Linux"); 
if (in_array("Irix", $os)) { 
    echo "Tem Irix";
}
if (in_array("mac", $os)) { 
    echo "Tem mac";
}

?>
```

Que é menos legível que isso:

[image: Codigo com realce de sintaxe]

Um segundo objetivo é criar um [Exemplo Mínimo, Completo e Verificável](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Se seu PHP for só um trecho, ok, mas se for algo que você pode copiar e colar num arquivo, executar, e ele vai demonstrar corretamente o que ele se propõe a fazer (i.e. o erro, se for código na pergunta, a solução, se for código na resposta), tanto melhor! Pensando nisso é que muitos usam sites como o jsFiddle, ideone, SQLFiddle, rubular e similares.

No caso específico das tecnologias usadas no *browser* (HTML/CSS/JS principalmente, mas a princípio poderia ser qualquer coisa igualmente suportada, como SVG), é oferecido o [Stack Snippets](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2115/215) como ferramenta complementar ("Trecho JavaScript/HTML/CSS Ctrl-M"). Com ele você pode escrever seu exemplo na pergunta/resposta mesmo (de modo que ele também entra no histórico de revisões), mas também executá-lo com o clique de um botão, e vê-lo funcionando. Evita ter o trabalho de sair do site pra testar o código. Ou seja, é bastante conveniente (mas não obrigatório).

Quando **não usar** o Stack Snippets, então? Um, quando a linguagem não for suportada pelo mesmo (se você escreve PHP em qualquer uma das áreas da ferramenta, dá no mesmo, pois o *browser* não vai conseguir executar aquilo como código); dois, quando não dá pra demonstrar o problema ali mesmo, ainda que a linguagem em si seja suportada (vai que seu problema precisa de Ajax, por exemplo, ou o código é muito extenso e sua dúvida é só num pequeno trecho).

Respondendo então à pergunta, a forma correta de publicar código PHP é através da formatação "amostra de código" e - se o realce de sintaxe não estiver presente ou estiver incorreto (ex.: a pergunta tem tanto a tag [php](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/php) quanto outra tag, tipo [javascript](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript)), ajuda também definir explicitamente qual a linguagem sendo empregada colocando esse comentário duas linhas antes do código de fato:

```
<!-- language: lang-php -->
```

(se não entendeu bem como usar por favor olhe o [markdown](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/editing-help) desta própria resposta para ver exemplos de como isso pode ser feito)