# Como fazer backup das perguntas?

Tags: suporte

**Existe alguma forma de fazer backup das minhas perguntas e favoritos ?**

**Espero que isso nunca aconteça**  , mas caso o site fique **indisponível** e nunca mais volte (drama total), como vou fazer se perder meus favoritos e minhas perguntas preciosas , eu tenho que salvar tudo manualmente ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Temos o [Data Explorer](https://data.stackexchange.com) (SEDE), que deixa rodar pesquisas na base de dados de todos os sites da rede. Mas se você quer uma maneira mais... "automatizável"... Os dados do SEDE também estão disponíveis no [Data Dump](https://archive.org/details/stackexchange), que é atualizado a cada 6 meses se não me engano.

A documentação sobre o esquema de banco de dados dos arquivos do Dump [está aqui](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/2678/), mas em inglês...
Não seria nada mal traduzirmos para o português e colocarmos no [nosso FAQ](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/699).