# Comentar ao invés de responder

Tags: debate, proposta-para-faq

Eu li o topico [FAQ da comunidade](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/699/faq-da-comunidade) e não encontrei um motivo para esse comportamento aqui no StackOverflow.

Eu vejo uma grande quantidade de questoes sem respostas, mas altamente comentadas.
O que eu noto é que existe uma tendencia à tentar responder as questoes nos comentários ([aqui um exemplo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/133559/concorr%C3%AAncia-server-asp-net)) sem gerar uma reposta.

O que eu procuro é um FAQ de como melhor usar os comentários.Estou acostumado (mal?) a outros fóruns e o SO é o primeiro que eu vejo com essa dinamica.

Grato

William

Comment: Um detalhe, o [pt.so] [**não é um fórum**](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/2068/18246)

Comment: @jbueno isso eu já entendi, mas é nessa transição de fórum para o SO (como o SO poderia ser definido?) é que eu me perco.

Comment: @WilliamJohnAdamTrindade é basicamente um site de perguntas e respostas. A dúvida da pergunta tem que ser autosuficiente para que alguém possa responder de maneira autosuficiente, de forma que lendo apenas a pergunta a dúvida esteja inteiramente clara, e lendo a resposta se tenha uma proposta factível de resolver o problema.

Comment: @WilliamJohnAdamTrindade o link está na 1a caixa amarela, logo no topo (tracejado embaixo). Caso por algum motivo não tenha aparecido, dê um refresh na página De qq forma, segue cópia http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/2333/

Comment: Algum moderador poderia exclui-la?

Comment: @WilliamJohnAdamTrindade não há necessidade, pode ser que em alguma pesquisa a sua seja achada mais facilmente, ajudando a localizar a original.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

O ideal é as respostas serem dadas quando há certeza do problema e com a solução. Até esse momento chegar, usamos os comentários.

Muitas vezes o que acontece é procurar perceber-se melhor o problema através de comentários, e dar sugestões sobre possíveis soluções, como é o caso que referes na pergunta.

Até haver certeza do problema deve usar-se os comentários para clarificar o problema. Quando há certeza de uma resposta que vá resolver o problema ela deve ser feita/criada.

Quando encontrares perguntas com a informação nos comentários que esclarece partes importantes do problema, as mesmas devem ser adicionadas à própria pergunta.

Quando encontrares respostas, confirmadas como solução pelo utilizador, podes avisar quem deu a sugestão que funcionou e convidar a dar uma resposta completa; **ou** dar tu próprio uma resposta.

Comment: Eventualmente eu posto uma resposta quando vejo que vale, assim: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A101+wiki%3Ayes

Comment: @bigown boa, _wiki_ é boa ideia e pode resumir o trabalho conjunto feito nos comentários.

Comment: A resposta não é minha, então passa ter uma resposta, e isso é importante e não me aproprio do conteúdo que foi gerado por outra pessoa, nos comentários, ou até na própria pergunta.